# onclick assignment vs init assignment discrepency

Tags: javascript, jscolor

**Updated:** Narrowed this down even further eliminating the aspx JavaScript reference.
So it's down to this...if I uncomment the 1 line inside the init and remove the click event it behaves as expected. However, if I put the assignment statement inside my button click event I get the incorrect behavior as shown way down below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageDefault = {
        btn1: document.getElementById('Button1'),
        tdtarget: document.getElementById('targetTD'),
        bg: document.getElementById('txtBGColor'), //jscolor textbox
        init: function() {
            //pageDefault.bg.value = pageDefault.tdtarget.getAttribute('bgcolor'); 
            this.btn1.onclick = function() {
                pageDefault.bg.value =
                    pageDefault.tdtarget.getAttribute('bgcolor');
            }
        }
    }
    pageDefault.init();
```

I am using jscolor. I am experience 2 different behaviors, one of which I don't understand.

All I'm trying to do is get the background color from a `<TD>` element of a `<Table>` and show the color value in a jscolor textbox.

[image]

Comment: Why would you include javascript as content in an aspx file? I can't think of a reason this would cause a problem, but you're sure going to a lot of trouble with setting mime types and so on when all you need to do is put it in a file called "myjavascript.js"

Comment: The hand that i've been dealt

Comment: @jamietre ok, I was able to rule out the aspx JavaScript script reference. Please see my update in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on their website. I did look at it before but just had to narrow it down this far. Thanks for feedback and time (views).

```
pageDefault.bg.color.fromString('ffcc99');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pageDefault.bg.value = pageDefault.tdtarget.getAttribute('bgcolor').replace(/#/, '');
```

Comment: what actually happens when it works as expected is the string color can look like "#ffcc99" and when you assign it to the jscolor text it automatically converts to uppcase and sets the background of the textbox as well.

Comment: Consider making an example of how it doesn't work in JSFiddle for us?